# Trying to make a menu not hoverable

Tags: jquery, joomla, zurb-foundation

Zurb foundation has an option to not make your hoverable.

Here's *their* code example to add this option: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html#clickable

Or here's the code: 
    `<nav class="top-bar" data-options="is_hover:false">`

I have  that in my code, but the menu persists to be hoverable. I'm wondering why.

Here's my menu code (sorry it's such a mess - btw, this is generated code - if you want code as in template, that's after *this* code sample:

Any help would be appreciated.

By the way, if there's any info I left out of my question, or if it's not clear, please do let me know.

Thank you.

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="contain-to-grid">
          <nav class="top-bar" data-options="is_hover:false">
            <ul class="title-area">
              <li class="name"><!-- Leave this empty --></li>
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
       <ul class="nav menu left">
<li class="item-101 current active">
    <a href="/social/services/" >Home</a></li>
<li class="item-106 deeper parent">
   <a class="programs" href="/social/services/index.php/programs-services" >Programs &amp; Services</a>

<ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
  <li class="item-112">
    <a href="/social/services/index.php/programs-services/children-family" >Children &amp; Family</a></li>
   <li class="item-114"><a href="/social/services/index.php/programs-services/senior-services" >Senior Services</a></li>
   <li class="item-115"><a href="/social/services/index.php/programs-services/support-groups" >Support Groups</a></li>
    <li class="item-113"><a href="/social/services/index.php/programs-services/counseling" >Counseling</a></li>
   </ul></li>
    <li class="item-108 deeper parent">
      <a href="/social/services/index.php/news" >News</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
     <li class="item-126">
      <a href="/social/services/index.php/news/ltsc-news" >LTSC News</a></li>
      </ul></li>
       <li class="item-109 deeper parent">
         <a href="/social/services/index.php/resources" >Resources</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
       <li class="item-102"><a href="/social/services/index.php/resources/testing" >Testing</a></li><li class="item-125">
          <a href="/social/services/index.php/resources/children-family" >Children &amp; Family</a></li></ul></li>
        <li class="item-116"><a href="/social/services/index.php/get-involved" >Get Involved</a></li>
         <li class="item-111"><a href="/social/services/index.php/contact-us" >Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="item-117 deeper parent"><a href="/social/services/index.php/calendar" >Calendar</a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class="item-123"><a href="/social/services/index.php/calendar/upcoming-events" >Upcoming Events</a></li>
          <li class="item-124"><a href="/social/services/index.php/calendar/past-events" >Past Events</a></li>
              </ul></li></ul>

  </section>
            </nav>
 </div>

  <!-- End Navigation -->
```

This is code as in the template (ie, not generated as above)

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="contain-to-grid">
          <nav class="top-bar" data-options="is_hover:false">
            <ul class="title-area">
              <li class="name"><!-- Leave this empty --></li>
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
       <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu2" style="none" />    
  </section>
            </nav>
 </div>

  <!-- End Navigation -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Foundation 5.0? They recently changed how this works and [can be found in their upgrading documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html).

In Foundation 4.0 you could remove it by using this javascript:

```
$(document).foundation('dropdown', {is_hover: false});
```

However in the new Foundation 5.0 you'll need to use this instead:

```
$(document).foundation({dropdown: {is_hover: false}});
```